# What is the upgrade path for C# MSBuild Tools to be?

Tags: msbuild, bamboo

We are using Bamboo to compile our C# projects and recently enhanced our build AMIs to have the MsBuild 15 Build Tools so devs are able to use C#7. With the advent of C# 7.1, Microsoft state they are "increasing the cadence" of language releases and I've been trying to find out what the upgrade path for MS Build Tools and how to keep it updated with the latest version.

At the moment it appears that the Bamboo admins would have to always be one step ahead of the devs (who update their IDE to use the new language release) to enable clean compilations.

I can't find a decent way of automating this (other than though something like Chocolatey) - I'd be interested to see how other people get round this or ensure their Build Tools will always up to date.

Comment: In how far is tools management related to C or C# language?

Comment: Have removed the C# tags to reclassify